# sh script that looks for a word in a .txt document and shows all the occurrences of said word in the .txt document

Tags: shell, sh

This doesn't sound very complicated but I have been browsing the internet for a while now and I can't figure out how to do it. I need a script that looks for a word in a file, let's say that word is A1B-3, the word is a variable. It should then go through the file and in the terminal give me all the occurrences of the word and "parts" of the word, so in this case it should show me all the occurrences of A1B-3, A1B and A1. Now I tried doing something with grep but it only shows me occurrences of the whole word A1B-3 and not the parts of it. Shouldn't I use grep here?

My code is:

`#!/bin/sh
grep $1 text.txt`

$1 is the input of the word when calling the script, I would also like to make so that the when I call it I write the filename before the word, I tried it but it all went wrong.

Comment: In order to be a solvable problem, you need to define the problem correctly. Ie. what does "parts of the word" mean? Also, to have grep print the filename before each occurrence, you supply it multiple input files, eg. an empty file and the file you want searched. For empty file you can use /dev/null. A google search would have found that.

Comment: based on your current description, you can use grep, but you'll have to pre-"parse" your search target to create the multiple search targets you're interested in finding. And of course, if you find `A1` and/or `A1B` you will automatically find `A1B-3`, AND why aren't you interested in `B-3` as a "part"? Agree with above that this problem definition seems weak and that you may know what you want, but we can't read your mind ;-) (Sorry!) ... A starting point for your example is `grep -e 'A1|A1B|B-3' file /dev/null`  Good luck.